# add full path to base href in Angular

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I want to get the base href in Angular including the domain (or subdomain)

use case:

I want to add `ogg:image` property using Meta service.
the current content looks like `/image.jpg` but I want it to be `https://example.com/image.jpg` so it can be fetched properly by social media platforms.

note: I use SSR.

Answer (score 0):

We do something related in our app-config.service.ts, where the URI lib will parse it for you `const { scheme, host, path } = URI.parse(window.location.href);`

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { tap, concatMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as URI from 'uri-js';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AppConfigService {
    public config?: {} = {};
    private env?: {} = {};

    constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {
        this.getHostBase();
    }

    /**
     * Use to get the data found in the second file (config file)
     */
    public getConfig(key: any) {
        return this.config[key];
    }

    /**
     * Use to get the data found in the first file (env file)
     */
    public getEnv(key: any) {
        return this.env[key];
    }

    /**
     * This method:
     *   a) Loads "env.json" to get the current working environment (e.g.: 'production', 'development')
     *   b) Loads "config.[env].json" to get all env's variables (e.g.: 'config.development.json')
     */
    public load(): any {        
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            this.http
                .get('assets/env.json')
                .pipe(
                    catchError((): any => {
                        resolve(true);
                    }),
                )
                .subscribe((envResponse: any) => {
                    this.env = envResponse;
                    const request = this.http.get(`assets/config.${envResponse.env}.json`);

                    if (request !== undefined) {
                        request
                            .pipe(
                                catchError((error: any): any => {
                                    resolve(true);
                                }),
                            )
                            .subscribe((responseData: object) => {
                                this.config = { ...this.config, ...responseData };
                                resolve(true);
                            });
                    } else {
                        resolve(true);
                    }
                });
        });
    }

    public get host(): string | undefined {
        return this.getConfig('api');
    }

    private getHostBase(): void {
        const { scheme, host, path } = URI.parse(window.location.href);
       
        this.config['host'] = URI.serialize({ scheme, host, path: `${cleanPath}/` });
        this.config['api'] = URI.serialize({ scheme, host, path: `${cleanPath}/api/` });
        
    }
}
```

You can see that we build the final URLs here: `const { scheme, host, path } = URI.parse(window.location.href);`

Comment: I got ` URI is not defined`, also where should I put this snippet?

Comment: sorry I missed a piece. uri-js is a package which was added to our package.json in our Angular project. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/urijs. Then make sure you import it in your service code - i.e. `import * as URI from 'uri-js';
`

Comment: look at getHostBase() function above. The URI lib will parse out the URL and return three vars for  you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Document.location.origin`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location - note that you have to *inject the Document Object* when using SRR (instead of just using the global `document` object).

**Code example**

```
class UrlService {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
              private router: Router) {}

  getOrigin(): string {
    return this.document.location.origin;
  }

  getPath(): string {
    return this.router.url;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried injecting `REQUEST` as request, and then `let baseURI= ${this.request.protocol}://${this.request.hostname}/` and it worked. which one of these two solutions do you recommend and why?

Comment: @Sheldeeb That's interesting, I didn't know about `@Inject(REQUEST)` and couldn't really find documentation for it, apart from a [ng-universal Issue on Github](https://github.com/nestjs/ng-universal/issues/8)... I would rather use the `DOCUMENT` method, because it's documented (or should I say DOCUMENTed ;) in the [Angular Guides](https://angular.io/guide/universal#working-around-the-browser-apis).

Comment: apart from the DOCUMENTation, this is not the REQUESTed inquery. I just want to know which of them makes the best practice